# Using thermal fuses in parallel?

Tags: fuses

If one has some [216C 10A thermal fuses](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078GTZ9QV), could one wire two in parallel in order to fuse a 10A heated bed on a 3d printer? The bed is 110V and 1100W btw, so in normal operation it should draw 10A. Seeing as how this is right at the top of the current range, I thought I would put two side by side just to be safe.

I can't think of any reason this would not work, theoretically the current should be pretty evenly divided between the two, no?

**edit:** this is not a duplicate question! Why is everyone so quick to mark things duplicate on here before even reading the whole post?!? The "duplicate" question is even asking about fuses of different ratings- my fuses are identical.

The arguments linked in the other posts all have to do with current-limiting fuses. Thermal fuses blow at a particular temperature, and as long as they are within their rated current, one does not expect them to be used to limit current.

Again- two fuses in parallel, if given 10A, will theoretically each carry 5A. Even if the fuses are terribly mismatched, due to manufacturing irregularities, and one carries 8A and the other carries 2A, this is fine because we are concerned about max temp, not max current. As long as the second fuse takes at least 1A, then the other can take 9A and they will both be under the rated 10A. Then if the temperature happens to climb to 216C, they will blow. Why would this not work?

And if the answer is still no, at what current would they be acceptable to use in parallel?

Comment: Asked too often on here, no is the response.

Comment: @SolarMike If it's asked 'too often' then you can find a duplicate question, right?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I can use the search same as you and the op...

Comment: See this for one, while the values are different the arguments are not : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/169413/152903

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to combine two fuses together (with different current rating) to make a bigger fuse?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282839/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-fuses-together-with-different-current-rating-to)

Comment: "my fuses are identical" - No, they're not. They are **nominally** the same, but nothing in practice is really the same. It makes no difference whether they are the same nominal value or different, the answer is the same.

Comment: It is not true that this question is being "asked too often" here, nor is it a duplicate. There has never been a good general answer given on any question about a *reasonable* parallel use of breakers. By reasonable I mean same rating.

After all, a breaker pair on a branch with 2 hot phases is also in a way "parallel", but they have their switches mechanically bonded, all interesting features to discuss.

Comment: @SolarMike 4 years on :-). I'd argue that his case is benigh enough to be different. An 80V**DC** 500A circuit I'd treat with the utmost care and respect. A fusing arc would be fantastic, and scary, to see. A 10A fuse at 110 V**AC** needs due care but is not in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

To cool down emitions around "Is the question duplicate/or not" - i will just answer this one.

**(1) Fuses in parallel:**

You can place fuses in parallel, however this does not "double" the nominal current rating. Therefore, it is - besides high reliability system where a "false-fuse trip" is to be covered - useless.

**(2) But why?**

Fuses - and specifically thermal fuses - are not just "switches" which trigger at a given current or temperatur.

They have a resistance *R(I,T,V)* which is variant on *T=Temprature, I=Current, and V=Production variance*.

If you model two resistors in parallel, the current is equal as long as *R1=R2*.
But, due to the *V-dependence* this will "never be applicable" in reality. These are "real devices", so they differ in parameters.

**Therefore current sharing is not equal.**

**(3) My opinion:**

In a device you are going to get certified, you intend to sell, or you want to use without problems: **Big no no!**.

However: Prototyping, waiting for "actual parts" to arrive, "I couldn't care less"... Why not? By paralleling two 10A fuses, you will maybe get a 15A nominal rating out of it, before one fuses trips and the second one trips shortly after that.

**(4) In conclusion:**

Just get a *Inom x 2* fuse. So in your case a 20A device.

Comment: Would the significant temp coefficient not cause the fuses to balance? I would think it would.

Comment: @Drew To some degree for sure. 100% - dont think so. Also, the tempco varies from device to device, and from application to application. Small airflow over one fuse only, one fuse closer to a heatsink, one fuse absorbs a bigger impuls from a transient and so on. Steady state maybe.

Comment: I wrote an "answer" yesterday and then deleted it (at least for now. A **vital** point to note here is that these are NOT current tripped fuses. They are trpped by external temperature. This makes an immense difference to answers (or should :-) ).There will be SOME contribution from internal current based heating BUT this may be small (and specs are not available for the  fuses in question) and a competent fuse designer would keep it as small as possible to make the fusing temperature as coniustent as possible across the current range.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cantherm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/SDF_JUNE_2016.pdf) is a datasheet for a formally specified product. In the graph on page 4 it  shows a 11 degrees C temperature rise due to self heating  at rate max current (15A in this case). ie trip temperature would be about 11 C lower at full current than at no current || A say 10A device operated at say 15A would (very probably) not have a self heating temperature high enough to trip but may fail for other reasons.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sir, this indeed is a **vital point, that should make a difference to the answers**. I assumed, these devices with either trip on over-temperatur **logic or** on over current. Should have invested more than 3seconds looking at the product page.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent  It's an easy trap to fall into. I'm 72, I've been playing with "electrical stuff " for 62+ years, I've a Masters degree in electrical engineering, and decades of EE work and I've used thermal fuses. AND I still only realised that I hadn't taken account of the fuse properties properly after I'd written most of an answer.|| In this case we don't know for sure what happens if you CURRENT overload a thermally activated fuse at well below thermal trip temperature. You and I have both learned something:-). || Also note that HIS selected fuse may NOT have formal specs available.

Comment: Here is a superb [Microtemp thermal cutoff datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1702837.pdf) that allows various "what ifs" to be explored. || They say " ... application testing.
The proper calibration will be affected by application variables such as I2
R self heating of the TCO, heat transfer through insulation and heat dissipation due to heat sinking and air flow ." |||| & " ... overshoot temperatures after the opening of the thermal cutoff should be minimized to avoid dielectric breakdown and reconduction of the thermal cutoff. ..." || And MUCH more